# relogin not success after logout with live window app

Tags: authentication, logout

I have a Windows Live Application and it use login.live.com to login or logout my app. 
When I login with login.live.com url then I logout  but I can't relogin after I logout .

If I off the browser then launch it again or logined for along time,  I can relogin successfully. 
I know the live cookie is problem but I can't find the solution for this problem .